# Play an audio with the preloading concept

Tags: ionic-framework, media-player, media, ionic-native

I am creating a media player. Where I want an audio file to be played with the preloading concept. I am trying to use ionic preloading plugins, but they only work with local storage file not if the audio URL starts with HTTPS:

Can anyone help me with this?